# How to change the width of an infopath webpart in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, infopath, css

I have this one edit form for a list that was designed in infopath, and I'm trying to set the width to a fix value of 1200px. However, I don't see an option to configure the width in Infopath. When I try to add CSS to the page, I was only able to change the width of the webpart containing the form but not the form itself.

Does anyone know either the CSS path to reach the form or another method to changing the width displayed in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the background of the form, select "table properties" > "column" > then set the width to 1200px.
I picked this up when I had a massive amount of white space at the end of my form, I was really confused until i found a row that was set to 24000px.  An easy fix for an annoying issue

Easy as that :)